# Robust way to detect if file has changed

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, posix

I *think* this question hasn't been answered for my use-case.

We wish to detect if the user has changed a file without re-reading its contents for the purposes of caching a computation result based on the file contents. Our program is a long-running one that lets the user click a button to perform a computation based on data entered in the program and data stored in external files (sorry, I can't be more specific than that). The external data needs to be read, processed and various data structures need to be built based on it, so we try to cache those between computations to speed up re-computes when the user changes the data in the program itself, but not the data in the external files. However, if the external file has changed, we have to re-read that.

For each external resource we're checking if the modification time and file size have changed, but that's not really all that robust and can lead to user frustration if they have e.g. fileA and fileB with the same size and timestamp and copy or fileA to fileC, use fileC as an external resource, and then copy fileB to fileC. The system preserves the modification time of the original file and the sizes are the same, so we don't re-read the external resource.

Our program runs on Windows, macOS and Linux, is written in C++ and we're perfectly OK with using platform-specific code to detect file changes. We're interested in the most robust way to detect if the contents of a file identified by a file path have changed without actually reading the file itself.

Comment: Have you tried to using a checksum of the file?

Comment: @Rik Well, determining the checksum would need to read the complete file, unless it's stored in some kind of header information. The latter case would allow to compare for a least noticed checksum, assumed it's updated along any write operation to that file.

Answer (score 3):

I've made this answer a community wiki so others can add their ideas for the various platforms listed in the question.

## Linux

## MacOS

## Windows

### Option 1

Set up a thread that [watches the directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx) containing the file.  When the directory changes, you'll have to check if the file you care about has actually changed.  That may mean opening and re-reading the file, (e.g., to compute the current checksum).  But since you have to do this only after a change notification, this overhead may be acceptable.

I believe (but have not verified) that if someone copies a same-size, same-timestamp file over an existing file, you'll get a directory change notification.

### Option 2

Hold the file open with an [opportunistic lock](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130415-00/?p=4663).  This involves creating the lock with a call to `DeviceIoControl` and then issuing a blocking call to `GetOverlappedResult`, which will unblock when another process attempts to change the file.  Your program can the release the lock, allowing the other process to update the file, and know that the file is being changed.